# `mat-dialog-content`, `mat-dialog-actions` are `directive` or `component`?

Tags: angular, angular-material

`mat-dialog-content`, `mat-dialog-actions` are `directive` or `component` ?

Is it possible to use `mat-dialog-content` , `mat-dialog-actions`  as directive or component :

somewhere I have seen, the programmers used them as a directive and some places the used them as component?

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of Directive in `MatDialogModule` including `mat-dialog-content` , `mat-dialog-actions`.

If you look at the source of components/src/material/dialog/dialog-module.ts in Angular Materials [git repo](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/dialog/dialog-module.ts), it exports the following directives.

```
import {
  MatDialogActions,
  MatDialogClose,
  MatDialogContent,
  MatDialogTitle,
} from './dialog-content-directives';

exports: [
    ...
    MatDialogClose,
    MatDialogTitle,
    MatDialogContent,
    MatDialogActions,
    ...
  ]
```

and with following similar declaration for each directive in `~/dialog-content-directives.ts`

```
@Directive({
  selector: `[mat-dialog-content], mat-dialog-content, [matDialogContent]`,
  host: {'class': 'mat-dialog-content'}
})
export class MatDialogContent {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do both:

```
<div mat-dialog-content></div>
<div mat-dialog-actions></div>
```

Or

```
<mat-dialog-content></mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions></mat-dialog-actions>
```

The choice depends on your use case and the way you organize your code.

Comment: It appears many people have an issue using them as directives, and this is related to how the project's modules are set up. I'm on a project I didn't set up, and can't seem to use the directives without build errors, but the modules appear correct according to the documentation. Does not compute.